# ANT / JMeter - long running test - stops writing the summariser results

Tags: java, ant, jmeter

I have a WebService & I hit that WebService once for every 2 seconds with 1 user using jmeter for 5 days continuously. 
I invoke JMeter using ANT. I set 4GB heap size for jmeter using ANT while invoking jmeter. I do not have any ANT_OPTS set for ANT. (I am not sure of the default heap size ANT will take)

When i start the jmeter test, it works fine. I get the jmeter summariser output in the console for 30 every 30 seconds which is great.

Problem is  - After 3 or 4 days, It stops writing the summariser results in the console (first 3 days it works really fine. no issues). ANT build does not complete yet. It is still running.
Looks like jmeter stops working/hanging. But I do not think it uses the 4GB as i see more free memory available. I do not see any exception in the log anywhere. The API is still running good if i try to access it.
Is it an issue with ANT / jmeter? Should i allocate more space for ANT for this long running ANT target?

Tried 2 times. First time it ran for 3 days w/o any issues. Second time almost 4 days w/o any issues. But It does not run for 5 days continuously.

Note:

It is nothing to do with the WebService server. The jmeter machine has 16GB RAM. I do not run anything else except this test (ANT & jmeter).

I use SOAP/XML RPC sampler in JMeter

Comment: any feedback on my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set on HTTP Request:

- Connect Timeout
- Response Timeout

Use HTTP Request Defaults to set those so that they are applied to all requests:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults

It is possible that your underlying server is experiencing issues or that the network is experiencing issues.

If you do not set one of these, then in this case JMeter will wait infinitely (by default) for response that never comes, giving you the impression it is hanging which is not the case.

Comment: As i said, it is not server issue as it works great. What is the default Response timeout ? will jmeter wait for more than 1 day for response?

Comment: JMeter will wait infinitely by default

Comment: seriously? I thought 300 seconds is the default value! you know the property names?

Comment: I think this is the one - httpclient.timeout

Comment: Sorry that i gave wrong information in my question that it is a Webservice. I send SOAP/XML RPC request. But i think i can still use the same property - `httpclient.timeout ` for setting the timeout. I will check. But i would know the answer only after 5 days :).

Comment: I am not sure, you should update your way of call webservices , read this : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html It is the up to date way of doing webservice, using this method will allow you to use HTTP Request Default. If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote